# How to make a path that always points to the root directory of my website?

Tags: php, html

I want to make a path to be used with links and src attributes in my html - how do i achieve this?

my attempts:

```
<a href="' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '">Home</a>
```

or

```
<img src="' . $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '.images/whatever.jpg">
```

Can anyone expound upon this?

Comment: it needs to be echo'd, if you're not already doing so.

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between $\_SERVER\['DOCUMENT\_ROOT'\] and $\_SERVER\['HTTP\_HOST'\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229783/difference-between-serverdocument-root-and-serverhttp-host)

Comment: no its not a duplicate - i simply want to know how to make a dynamic link that always goes to my root folder of my website, that is all - i know im not good at asking these questions - but that is what i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` returns that path to the document root *on the server*, for instance: `/var/www/my.website.org/src` or `C:/wamp/www/my.website.org/src`.

You shouldn't use it to make URLs directly, you can use it to make relative paths, for instance:

```
$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
$file_path = __FILE__;
$relative_file_path = str_replace($root, "", $file_path); // needs better logic but works in some cases

$base_url = "http://my.website.org/";
$url = $base_url . $relative_file_path; // http://www.mywebsite.org/path/to/file.php
```

Comment: im going to give this a go - comment back later