# How do I edit multiple .txt files with different names in a folder?

Tags: php, file-get-contents, str-replace

I have a folder that contains several .txt files called :

```
A500_1.txt

A500_2.txt

A700_1.txt

A700_2.txt

A900_1.txt

...
```

In each of the .txt files there is :

```
PRXC1_|TB|CCAAO9-RC|9353970324463|24.99

PRXC1_|TB|CFEXK4-RC|9353970294766|84.99

PRXC1_|TB|CFEXK4-RC|9353970294773|84.99

...
```

I'd like you to :

- if the filename starts with A500_ replace "TB" with "MD"
- if the filename starts with A700_ replace "TB" by "JB"
- if the filename senter code heretarts with A900_ replace "TB" with "LD"

I wrote this function but it just creates me an empty A500_2.TXT file at the root of the project and displays :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(A500_2.TXT): failed to open stream:
```

Where's my error?

```
<?php

function processFile( $path ) {

   $dir    = './test/';
   $allFiles = scandir($dir);

   foreach($allFiles as $file) {

       $filename = basename( $file );

        if ( ! in_array($file,array(".","..")))
      { 

       //read the entire string
       $str = file_get_contents( $file );

       // var_dump($str);

       // replace something in the file string
       if ( strpos( $filename, 'A500_' ) === 0 ) {

           $str = str_replace( 'TB', 'MD', $str );

       } else if ( strpos( $filename, 'A700_' ) === 0 ) {

           $str = str_replace( 'TB', 'JB', $str );

       } else if ( strpos( $filename, 'A900_' ) === 0 ) {

           $str = str_replace( 'TB', 'LD', $str );

       } else {
           // Return false if we don't know what to do with this file
           return false;
       }

       //write the entire string    
       $writeResult = file_put_contents( $file, $str );

       //return true after a file is written successfully, or false on failure
       return $writeResult >= 0;

  }
  }
}

if(processFile( './test/' )) echo "good!";
?>
```

Comment: what is your [**PHP Current Working Directory**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php)? You should give PHP an absolute directory to open the file, because "A500_2.TXT" is just a file that sits in the same folder as the script that is running.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `file_get_contents($dir.$file)`?

Comment: If I put file_get_contents($dir.$file) it will create a file A500_2.TXT at the root of the folder by changing the TB by MD but not in my test folder.

Comment: Eric, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60544242/3536236) is an answer to a different question but the same thing will work for you -- you should be using **absolute filepathing with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`**. If That still is not working, *then* look at permission issues

Comment: @Eric27  "but not in my test folder"  Because you need to do the same thing on your `file_put_contents()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `file_get_contents` warning and the blank file being created are down to the same problem - `scandir` returns *just the filename*, not a relative path to the currently running script.

I'd guess that you're expecting it to return relative paths, which is why you're calling `basename` at the top of your loop. As it is, your `$file` and `$filename` arguments are going to always be set to the same thing.

The quickest solution will be to prepend `$file` with the scanned directory name before processing anything else:

```
$file = $dir . $file;
```

This should fix both the read and write calls.

Comment: It changes me that the file A500_2.TXT but not all those in my folder

Comment: @Eric27 Oh sorry, I should have noticed that. Your function is set to `return` at the bottom of the foreach loop, which means it can only ever process one file. You'll need to remove that if you want it to actually process the whole folder.